# How to add a gradient to a Button in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

Is there a way to change the `ElevatedButton` background color to a gradient?

Comment: I've had trouble in the past adding a background gradient to an ink splash area. The gradient ends up hiding splashes. Are you interested in just having a gradient or having a gradient with a splash effect? (as for a button with elevation, border radius, and gradient - yes that's possible

Comment: @AshtonThomas As you said the gradient is hiding the ink splash . This is because the ink splash needs a Material widget as its parent. I had the same situation. So ended up creating my own custom button.

Comment: I tried the custom button idea and I can't implement the shadow animation that the default raised button have! could you help me with this?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

All the solution above are not really working without some minor artifacts or issues (e.g. missing ripple effect, unwanted borders, not respecting the theme's *minWidth* for buttons).

The **solution below has none of the above issues** (the critical part is to use the `Ink` widget to retain the ripple capabilities over the gradient):

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () { },
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80.0)),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
  child: Ink(
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      gradient: myGradient,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(80.0)),
    ),
    child: Container(
      constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 88.0, minHeight: 36.0), // min sizes for Material buttons
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: const Text(
        'OK',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

[image]

Comment: `RaisedButton` is now deprecated. Use `ElevatedButton` [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67570467/6618622)

Comment: I used this solution on `MaterialButton` and it works perfectly!

Comment: I hope this helps https://betterprogramming.pub/instagram-gradient-animation-for-flutter-1d74d3869997

Answer (score 71):

You can create a custom one yourself

```
class RaisedGradientButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Gradient gradient;
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final Function onPressed;

  const RaisedGradientButton({
    Key key,
    @required this.child,
    this.gradient,
    this.width = double.infinity,
    this.height = 50.0,
    this.onPressed,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: width,
      height: 50.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: gradient, boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.grey[500],
          offset: Offset(0.0, 1.5),
          blurRadius: 1.5,
        ),
      ]),
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: InkWell(
            onTap: onPressed,
            child: Center(
              child: child,
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And use it anywhere as follows:

```
RaisedGradientButton(
  child: Text(
    'Button',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  ),
  gradient: LinearGradient(
    colors: <Color>[Colors.green, Colors.black],
  ),
  onPressed: (){
    print('button clicked');
  }
),
```

[image: Custom button]

You can further play around with the shadow and rounded borders by editing the Container's decoration property until it matches your spec.

Comment: actually, I want the shadow to be exactly like default raised button and couldn't implement that.

Comment: Vamsi, @MoeinHosseini, try using adding an `elevation` to the material rather than a shadow

Comment: This is missing some functionalities that the button has. For example Semantics.

Answer (score 27):

## Update:

Since `RaisedButton` and `OutlineButton` are deprecated, you should use `ElevatedButton` and `OutlinedButton`.

- #### `ElevatedButton`

  [image]

  ```dart
  Container(
    height: 44.0,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.pink, Colors.green])),
    child: ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, shadowColor: Colors.transparent),
      child: Text('Elevated Button'),
    ),
  )
  ```

---

- #### `OutlinedButton`

  [image]

  **Create a class** (null-safe):

  ```dart
  class MyOutlinedButton extends StatelessWidget {
    final VoidCallback onPressed;
    final Widget child;
    final ButtonStyle? style;
    final Gradient? gradient;
    final double thickness;

    const MyOutlinedButton({
      super.key,
      required this.onPressed,
      required this.child,
      this.style,
      this.gradient,
      this.thickness = 2,
    });

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return DecoratedBox(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: gradient),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(thickness),
          child: OutlinedButton(
            onPressed: onPressed,
            style: style,
            child: child,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
  ```

  **Usage**:

  ```dart
  MyOutlinedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.indigo, Colors.pink]),
    child: Text('OutlinedButton'),
  )
  ```

Comment: Thanks, this is the first solution I have found using elevated button! 

To remove the shadow effect, use the following style on the elevated button:
`ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.transparent, elevation: 0,),`

Comment: The `primary` property has been deprecated since v3.1.0. To achieve transparency and remove the shadow, both `backgroundColor: Colors.transparent` and `elevation: 0` need to be added as you mentioned.

Final: `ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, elevation: 0,)`

Answer (score 16):

Refer Below -

```
RaisedButton(
     onPressed: () {},
     textColor: Colors.white,
     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
     shape:RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80.0)),
     child: Container(
       decoration: const BoxDecoration(
         gradient: LinearGradient(
           colors: <Color>[
             Color(0xFF0D47A1),
             Color(0xFF1976D2),
             Color(0xFF42A5F5),
           ],
         ),
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(80.0))
       ),
       padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 10),
       child: const Text(
           'Gradient Button',
           style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)
       ),
     ),
   )
```

Answer (score 9):

[Gradient](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/gradient_widgets#-readme-tab-) package is available at pub store which supports few predefined gradients

You can create the gradient button as

```
GradientButton(
                 child: Text('Gradient'),
                 callback: () {},
                 gradient: Gradients.backToFuture,
           ),
```

The package have GradientCard, GradientProgressIndicator, GradientButton, CircularGradientButton and the GradientText

[Gradient Widgets](https://github.com/bluemix/gradient-widgets/raw/master/art/screenshot3_cropped_resized.png)

Answer (score 8):

The Flutter API doc has an example of how to render a `RaisedButton` with gradient background - see here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html

```
Widget gradientButton = Container(
  child: RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () { },
    textColor: Colors.white,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
    child: Container(
      width: 300,
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        gradient: new LinearGradient(
          colors: [
            Color.fromARGB(255, 148, 231, 225),
            Color.fromARGB(255, 62, 182, 226)
          ],
        )
      ),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Text(
        "Gradient Button",
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

[image: Gradient Button]

Comment: Unrelated question here. What font are you using with that button?

Comment: @AsyrafDayan [Montserrat](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat)

Answer (score 5):

Simply make one more container as a child set the decoration of that container and make gradient color as you want

Then after this use **RaisedButton** as the child of the above container 
same as with **MaterialButton** also

```
   child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [Colors.red, Colors.blue],
            begin: FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
            end: FractionalOffset(0.5, 0.0),
            stops: [0.0, 1.0],
            tileMode: TileMode.clamp),
      ),
      child: RaisedButton(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: Text("Ask Permssion"),
        onPressed: () {
          askPermission();
        },
      )),
```

**Output:**

[image: GradientRaisedButton]

Answer (score 2):

Docs last example https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  textColor: Colors.white,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
  child: Container(
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        colors: <Color>[
          Color(0xFF0D47A1),
          Color(0xFF1976D2),
          Color(0xFF42A5F5),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    child: const Text(
      'Gradient Button',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a more easier way by using `RawMaterialButton` from `material.dart` , you can make it's shape as rounded or circle too .
here is a simple example of this .

```
  Card(
    elevation: 7,
    child: Container(
      width: 120.0,
      height: 75.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          end: Alignment.topRight,
          colors: <Color>[
            Colors.blue,
            Colors.red,
          ],
        ),
      ),
      child: RawMaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        splashColor: Colors.grey,
        child: Text(
          "Button",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old.. But I've found myself with this requirement and I wanted to share my solution. It uses a `Card` and animates the elevation when the button is pressed.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GradientButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final String label;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final Gradient gradient;
  final double elevation;
  final double height;
  final TextStyle labelStyle;

  GradientButton({
    @required this.label,
    @required this.onPressed,
    @required this.gradient,
    this.elevation,
    this.height,
    this.labelStyle,
  })  : assert(label != null && onPressed != null),
        assert(gradient != null);

  @override
  _GradientButtonState createState() => _GradientButtonState();
}

class _GradientButtonState extends State<GradientButton> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation _animation;

  elevateUp(TapDownDetails details) {
    _animationController.forward();
  }

  elevateDown() {
    _animationController.reverse();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 50), vsync: this);
    _animation = Tween(begin: widget.elevation ?? 2.0, end: 12.0).animate(_animationController);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _animation,
      builder: (c, w) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTapDown: elevateUp,
          onTapCancel: elevateDown,
          onTapUp: (value) {
            elevateDown();
            widget.onPressed();
          },
          child: Card(
            elevation: _animation.value,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
            ),
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: widget.height ?? 50.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: widget.gradient,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  widget.label,
                  style: widget.labelStyle ?? Theme.of(context).textTheme.button,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

There's room for improving it (maybe you don't want those rounded borders by default), but hope can be useful for some of you :D

Answer (score 0):

This what worker for me. RaisedButton being deprecated i used ElevatedButton. So this should be the way to go.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MainButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget thechild;
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final Function theaction;

  const MainButton({
    Key key,
    @required this.thechild,
    this.width = double.infinity,
    this.height = 50.0,
    this.theaction,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: theaction,
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        primary: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 4.0,
        minimumSize: Size(88.0, 45.0),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
      ),
      child: Ink(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              stops: [
                0.1,
                0.8,
                0.9
              ],
              colors: [
                Color.fromARGB(255, 186, 252, 244),
                Color.fromARGB(255, 55, 183, 230),
                Color.fromARGB(255, 49, 175, 230),
              ]),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
        ),
        child: Container(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 88.0, minHeight: 45.0),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: thechild,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Usage**

Import first

```
import '../widgets/mainButton.dart';
```

**then**

```
MainButton(
                        thechild: Text(AppLocalization.translate('loginbtn'),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 20)),
                        theaction: () {},
                      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Result -

[image]

---

Code for `CustomGradientButton.dart`

```
class CustomGradientButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Gradient gradient;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final String text;

  const CustomGradientButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.gradient,
    required this.onPressed,
    required this.text,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 45.0, // Adjust the height as needed
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        style: ButtonStyle(
          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
            RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80.0),
            ),
          ),
          padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsetsGeometry>(
            const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          ),
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.transparent),
          overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.transparent),
          foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),
          minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all<Size>(
            const Size(88.0, 36.0),
          ),
          elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all<double>(0.0),
          textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all<TextStyle>(
            TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        child: Ink(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: gradient,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(80.0)),
          ),
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(text),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

How to call it

```
CustomGradientButton(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.green],
                      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      // Perform some action when the button is pressed
                      print('Button pressed!');
                    },
                    text: 'OK',
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good solution that can include theme color configuration simultaneously and also inherit most of the properties of ButtonThemeData.

```bash
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on macOS 14.2.1 23C71 darwin-arm64, locale zh-Hans-CN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.85.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

##### button.dart

```
// ignore_for_file: overridden_fields

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'button_theme.dart';

class GradientMaterialButton extends MaterialButton {
  const GradientMaterialButton({
    super.key,
    this.fillGradient,
    this.shadowColor,
    double? elevation,
    required super.onPressed,
    super.onLongPress,
    super.onHighlightChanged,
    super.mouseCursor,
    super.textTheme,
    super.textColor,
    super.disabledTextColor,
    super.colorBrightness = Brightness.dark,
    super.splashColor,
    super.padding,
    super.visualDensity,
    super.shape,
    super.clipBehavior = Clip.none,
    super.focusNode,
    super.autofocus = false,
    super.animationDuration,
    super.minWidth,
    super.height,
    super.enableFeedback = true,
    super.child,
  })  : usedElevation = elevation,
        materialTapTargetSize = MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
        color = Colors.transparent,
        disabledColor = Colors.transparent,
        focusColor = Colors.transparent,
        hoverColor = Colors.transparent,
        highlightColor = Colors.transparent,
        elevation = 0.0,
        focusElevation = 0.0,
        hoverElevation = 0.0,
        highlightElevation = 0.0,
        disabledElevation = 0.0;

  final Gradient? fillGradient;

  final Color? shadowColor;

  final double? usedElevation;

  @override
  final MaterialTapTargetSize materialTapTargetSize;
  @override
  final Color color;
  @override
  final Color disabledColor;
  @override
  final Color focusColor;
  @override
  final Color hoverColor;
  @override
  final Color highlightColor;
  @override
  final double elevation;
  @override
  final double focusElevation;
  @override
  final double hoverElevation;
  @override
  final double highlightElevation;
  @override
  final double disabledElevation;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context).extension<GradientMaterialButtonThemeData>();
    final background = Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      shape: shape ?? ButtonTheme.of(context).shape,
      elevation: usedElevation ?? theme?.elevation ?? 0.0,
      shadowColor: shadowColor ?? theme?.shadowColor,
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: animationDuration ?? kThemeChangeDuration,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: fillGradient ?? theme?.fillGradient,
        ),
      ),
    );
    return Stack(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      children: [
        Positioned.fill(child: background),
        super.build(context),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
    properties.add(DiagnosticsProperty<Gradient>('fillGradient', fillGradient, defaultValue: null));
    properties.add(ColorProperty('shadowColor', shadowColor, defaultValue: null));
    properties.add(DoubleProperty('usedElevation', usedElevation, defaultValue: null));
  }
}
```

##### button_theme.dart

```dart
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GradientMaterialButtonThemeData extends ThemeExtension<GradientMaterialButtonThemeData> {
  GradientMaterialButtonThemeData({
    this.fillGradient,
    this.shadowColor,
    this.elevation,
  });

  final Gradient? fillGradient;

  final Color? shadowColor;

  final double? elevation;

  @override
  ThemeExtension<GradientMaterialButtonThemeData> copyWith({
    Gradient? fillGradient,
    Color? shadowColor,
    double? elevation,
  }) =>
      GradientMaterialButtonThemeData(
        fillGradient: fillGradient ?? this.fillGradient,
        shadowColor: shadowColor ?? this.shadowColor,
        elevation: elevation ?? this.elevation,
      );

  @override
  ThemeExtension<GradientMaterialButtonThemeData> lerp(
    covariant GradientMaterialButtonThemeData? other,
    double t,
  ) =>
      GradientMaterialButtonThemeData(
        fillGradient: Gradient.lerp(fillGradient, other?.fillGradient, t),
        shadowColor: Color.lerp(shadowColor, other?.shadowColor, t),
        elevation: ui.lerpDouble(elevation, other?.elevation, t),
      );
}
```

##### main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'button_theme.dart';
import 'button.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Button Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
        buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
        ),
        textTheme: const TextTheme(
          labelLarge: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
        ),
        extensions: [
          GradientMaterialButtonThemeData(
            elevation: 5,
            shadowColor: const Color(0x52007DBF),
            fillGradient: const LinearGradient(colors: [Color(0xFF359EEB), Color(0xFF007DBF)]),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Button Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title)),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            GradientMaterialButton(
              // elevation: 5,
              // shadowColor: Colors.red,
              // fillGradient: const LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.red, Colors.blue]),
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const Text('GradientMaterialButton'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DecoratedBox(
    decoration: ShapeDecoration(
        shape:
            RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
        gradient: RadialGradient(
            radius: 2, colors: [Colors.white, Colors.redAccent]),),
     child:RaisedButton(),
),
```

Add Gradient To Any Widget Using DecoratedBox As Parent Widget

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSy2e.jpg)