# Two colors in FlatButton

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create button like this.

[image]

The below is the flat button code. But I'm not getting the desired result.

```
FlatButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            color: Colors.orange,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            child: Text(
              'NEXT',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6)),
            onPressed: () => _nextButtonTapped,
          )
```

How can I set two colors in the background of the flat button?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flutter - How to make a raised button that has a gradient background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52243364/flutter-how-to-make-a-raised-button-that-has-a-gradient-background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code with splash effect.

```
class SO extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const double br = 10;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Ink(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(br),
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment(.05, -1),
              end: Alignment(-.05, 1),
              stops: [.5, .5],
              colors: <Color>[
                Colors.deepOrange,
                Colors.orange,
              ],
            ),
          ),
          child: FlatButton(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(br)),
            textColor: Colors.white,
            materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
            onPressed: () {},
            splashColor: Colors.red,
            child: const Text(
              'this is a button',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

which gives

[image: sample]

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: by using the `Container` with such `gradient` you loose the ink splashes (they are not visible)

Comment: as pointed by @pskink I have added the ripple effect by replacing `Container` with `Ink`.

Comment: what's the point of using FlatButton in this case? isn't better to use the same Container with decorations + GestureDetector? :)

Comment: @Eugene you could do that but `FlatButton` takes care of dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
  height: 50.0,
  child: RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80.0)),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
    child: Ink(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.orange.shade100, Colors.orange.shade900],
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)
      ),
      child: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 100.0, minHeight: 50.0),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text(
          "Next",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
  }
}
```

https://dartpad.dev/d0d9fdb6cd8bc07a78056aad05e2199d

Comment: Its good but it is not same what I'm looking for. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: you can change `borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)` and `begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter`, to achieve somthing like yours