# How to make an ElevatedButton with a gradient background in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, button

I have found multiple examples on stack overflow of how to utilize a RaiseButton with a gradient background, but since the posting of those answers, RaiseButton has been deprecated.

Most solutions I have found for an ElevatedButton with a gradient background have been incomplete to some degree; either the gradient does not cover the entire background or the shadowing is off.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52243364/how-to-add-a-gradient-to-a-button-in-flutter/67570467#67570467) has been the most complete answer I have found, but the onPress elevation presents a jarring shadow.

Below I have posted an answer with my best attempt of an ElevatedButton with a gradient background (Q&A style). Please comment in ways you see my answer improved!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, I managed to recreate the ElevatedButton.

End result:

[image: Gradient Button]

Below is my code for a reusable gradient button.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GradientElevatedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const GradientElevatedButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    required this.onPressed,
    required this.linearGradient,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final LinearGradient linearGradient;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      // ElevatedButton has default 5 padding on top and bottom
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 5,
      ),
      // DecoratedBox contains our linear gradient
      child: DecoratedBox(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: linearGradient,
          // Round the DecoratedBox to match ElevatedButton
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        ),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: onPressed,
          // Duplicate the default styling of an ElevatedButton
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            // Enables us to see the BoxDecoration behind the ElevatedButton
            primary: Colors.transparent,
            // Fits the Ink in the BoxDecoration
            tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
          ).merge(
            ButtonStyle(
              // Elevation declared here so we can cover onPress elevation
              // Declaring in styleFrom does not allow for MaterialStateProperty
              elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(0),
            ),
          ),
          child: child,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```