# LinearGradient button figma to flutter

Tags: css, flutter

[image: Desired result]

My CSS:

```
background: linear-gradient(91.97deg, #F8A170 14.73%, #FFCD61 97.52%);
border-radius: 10px;
```

I want to go with flutter but when I give these colors to the container widget with child elevated button, I can't get the result I want. I made the button style transparent, but still I couldn't solve it.

Comment: you can follow similar to this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52243364/how-to-add-a-gradient-to-a-button-in-flutter

Comment: bro i looked this previously problem is that when i give my color I can't get the color I want

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below example code

Using Elevated Button

[image]

```
LinearGradient yellowLinearGradientValues() {
    return LinearGradient(
      colors: [Colors.orange, Color(0xffFFB800).withOpacity(0.65)],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            elevation: 0.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            primary: Colors.transparent,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            ),
            side: BorderSide(
              width: 0.0,
              color: Colors.orange,
              style: BorderStyle.none,
            ),
            tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
          ),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(8.0),
              ),
              gradient: yellowLinearGradientValues(),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 40.0,
                vertical: 8.0,
              ),
              child: Text(
                "Search a Room" ?? "",
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                maxLines: 1,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 24.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

```
LinearGradient yellowLinearGradientValues() {
    return LinearGradient(
      colors: [Colors.orange, Color(0xffFFB800).withOpacity(0.7)],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          style: ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),
            elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(0.0),
            padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.zero),
            tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
          ),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(8.0),
              ),
              gradient: yellowLinearGradientValues(),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 40.0,
                vertical: 8.0,
              ),
              child: Text(
                "Search a Room" ?? "",
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                maxLines: 1,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 24.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: bro, can you do it with elevated button that child of container widget?

Comment: Please check edited code and let me know if its meeting your requirements

Comment: thanks bro that's working but when i tried with elevatedbutton.styleform i couldn't.edit: i forgot the elevation :(

Comment: I have used elevated button. Please check

Comment: Please check edited code for changes using ElevatedButton.styleFrom `style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            elevation: 0.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            primary: Colors.transparent,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            ),
            side: BorderSide(
              width: 0.0,
              color: Colors.orange,
              style: BorderStyle.none,
            ),
            tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
          ),`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your image and css, You can simply decorate the style of `ElevatedButton`.

```dart
 DecoratedBox(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            gradient: const LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                Color(0xFFF8A170),
                Color(0xFFFFCD61),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 400,
            height: 75,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                elevation: 0,
                primary: Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const Text(
                "Search a room",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 22,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

[image]

More about
[DecoratedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DecoratedBox-class.html) and [ElevatedButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html)

Comment: bro, can you do it with elevated button that child of container widget?

Comment: I think we can decorate that, let me try, else you can wrap this widget with tappable widget to get the job done.

Comment: done with styling approach