# How to make gradient button in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, gradient

I am new to Flutter and I want to make like this gradient button in Flutter. you can also give tutorials to make this type of button.

I want that gradient on the right side, how to make it like in image. More I got from internet is just specifying 2 colors, that's all. but how to make gradient with in a different angle.

thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a gradient to a Button in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52243364/how-to-add-a-gradient-to-a-button-in-flutter)

Comment: no bro.  i want that gradient with that angle at the right side

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _Examplestate();
  }
}

class _Examplestate extends State<Example> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Stateful Widget'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: RadiantGradientMask(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                Colors.pink,
                Colors.red,
                Colors.orange,
              ],
            ),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.white),
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const Text(
                "Hello",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class RadiantGradientMask extends StatelessWidget {
  const RadiantGradientMask({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    required this.gradient,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final Widget child;
  final Gradient gradient;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ShaderMask(
      shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
        return gradient.createShader(bounds);
      },
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Result ->[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
DecoratedBox(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.pink, Colors.green])),
  child: ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.transparent),
    child: Text('Elevated Button'),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Looks to have been heavily based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67570467/4294399). If this is the case, please remember to cite.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use **begin, end** Properties of LinearGradient ([Source](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/LinearGradient-class.html))

```
gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.topLeft, <--------
        end: Alignment(0.8, 0.0), <--------
           colors: <Color>[
             Color(0xffee0000),
             Color(0xffeeee00)
  ],
),
```